# Why doesn't this invalid subquery raise a syntax error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

Is there any explanation so as to why SSMS did not raise any compilation error for the below delete query with a subquery that is invalid on its own?

Below is the sequence of steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[delete_test]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Seed data:

```
insert dbo.delete_test(name) values(N'a'),(N'b'),(N'c'),(N'd'),(N'e');
```

Create a backup table:

```
select id, name
  into dbo.delete_test_backup 
  from dbo.delete_test where id > 2;
```

Below statement should ideally not execute and, even if it executes, should only delete rows with `id` values that have been backed up :

```
delete dbo.delete_test where id in (
    select id delete_test_backup 
);
```

The message shows that 5 rows were deleted, but I expected only 3 rows to be deleted:

```
(5 row(s) affected)
```

Attempt to execute the sub-query as a standalone fails :

```
select id delete_test_backup ;
```

> Invalid column name 'id'

Below one executes as expected :

```
select id from dbo.delete_test_backup ;
```

> Output :

```
id
--
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the same as:

```
(
  SELECT id AS delete_test_backup
)
```

In other words, you have merely assigned a column alias to `id`, and there is no reference at all to a table called `delete_test_backup`.

According to the ANSI standard, what SQL Server is supposed to do in this case - when it has a subquery and does not find `id` at that scope - is traverse to the outer scope(s) until it finds one. If it does, it assumes that's the one you meant.

See:

- [Best practices : Properly referencing columns](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/best-practices-referencing-columns)
- <s>KB #298674</s>
- <s>Connect #735178</s>
- <s>Connect #624370</s>
- <s>Connect #392492</s>
- <s>Connect #362016</s>
- <s>Connect #265772</s>
- <s>Connect #772612</s>

> ** Microsoft decided to eradicate all of Connect instead of archiving the content, and also disappeared the knowledge base article for some reason.*

To avoid the problem, always use table aliases, which allow you to be 100% explicit about which table a column comes from (not naming every key column `id` helps, too). Of course you can leave these prefixes out accidentally, just like you left out the `FROM`, but the following syntax would have failed as you expect, and most other omissions would have left you with a parsing error rather than accidental execution:

```
(
  SELECT x.id FROM delete_test_backup AS x
)
```